# Sum Values Of One Column if Contiguous Value is a Pair Number

Tags: excel

First of all I apologise for my English if I made any mistake. 
I've got a matrix, two columns and 100 rows
Column A: Year => 1990, 1991, 1992... 
Column B: number => 45, 200, 67...

I need to get a the total amount of the sum of the values pertainig to the 'pair years'.

1990   45
1991  200
1992   67
.
.
Total = 45 + 67 + ....

I've tried many options but none of them worked. It seemed easy a first glance but I can't find the solution. I would appreciate any help or the whole solution to this problem. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: `pair years` means even yesrs?

Comment: @simoco: Yes, that is.

Comment: @simoco: The problem is I have two columns, in one years, on the other the amount of days I practice sport. I want to sum the days I have practised sport on even years. Column A: 2000, 2001, 2002... Column B: 300, 310, 260...   The solution sould recognize what is an even year and catch the related values and make the sum. In this case: 300 + 260 ....

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following with years in Column A and Days in column B

```
=SUMPRODUCT(1*(MOD(A:A,2)=0),B:B)
```

Although if possible I would prefer using a helper column in this situation.

In column C you could use the formula:

```
=MOD(A1,2)=0
```

And drag it down. Then in the cell you wish to have your results you could use:

```
=SUMIF(C:C,TRUE,B:B)
```

Comment: Perfect, it works great !! I was looking for a solution in a single formula. The one that begins with '=SUMPRODUCT' works just as I need. Thanks a lot to you USER2140261.